# How to bring a dropdown (Chosen) with selected value on page loads.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I am using [***Chosen plugin***](http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/Choosen/) for Select box.  I am replacing these both boxes on an ajax request.  I want the check box to be pre filled when it comes. I tried something and it fails.  I read the [***documentation***](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) of this and unable to accomplish. Here is what i have tried after reading the docs.  Once ajax response came i am doing these things.

```
var city = $('#hdnCity').val();
//**Ajax Request Goes and the response is here**//
$('#searchParams').html(responseText);
var value = $("#favCities1 option:contains("+city+")").attr('selected', 'selected');
$("#chzn-select").val(value).trigger("liszt:updated");
```

I am unable to accomplish this.  Helpers are appreciable. Thankyou in Advance!!!

Comment: can you share the ajax request also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the last line: `$("#chzn-select").val(value).trigger("liszt:updated");`

You will have to separate because `$("#chzn-select").val(value)` only returns jQuery object, but not the `<select>` element. Therefore, Chosen can't pick up the `liszt:updated` event since it's only listening to the `<select>`.

So you will have to do this:

```
$("#chzn-select").val(city);
$("#chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/amyamy86/qQCw8/

Comment: With respect to your fiddle,  You assigned Thanjavur and the selected value is Chennai.  Did you noticed that?

Comment: @VigneshGopalakrishnan Sorry, I assigned wrong variable, should be: `$("#chzn-select").val(city)`

Comment: Although it doesn't work.  Check with fiddle please.  I just hardcoded the city and though it fails to work.

Comment: Thankyou it works fine.  In multiple case how the values will affect?

Comment: @VigneshGopalakrishnan To set multiple values, just pass in *Array* into `.val()`. So `$(".chzn-select").val(["Thanjavor","Bangalore"])` would select both "Thanjavor" and "Bangalore" in the multiple select. However, the *single select* will only get set with the last value, so it would be "Bangalore".

Comment: Wow.  Very Nice.  Thankyou Very Much.

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of any further information, I guess it is a problem with how you are handling the ajax reponse

Updation of `searchParams` should happen within the ajax success callback

```
var city = $('#hdnCity').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '',
    ...
}).done(function(responseText){
    //**Ajax Request Goes and the response is here**//
    $('#searchParams').html(responseText);
    var value = $("#favCities1 option:contains("+city+")").attr('selected', 'selected').val();
    $("#chzn-select").val(value).trigger("liszt:updated");
})
```

Comment: I Thank your efforts Mr.Arun P Johny.  It also works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome requires that you fire a different event now, http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/. Without firing this event, the multiple select box wont get updated.

```
$('#chzn-select').trigger('chosen:updated')
```

You can see it in action with this jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/LjtVa/